# how to Pipe Magento2 logs to STDOUT?

Tags: magento2

How to store/write the logs inside STD-OUT instead of var/log folder in Magento2 root?

Is it possible to store the logs directly to syslog instead of var/log?

Comment: Magento uses [MonoLog](https://seldaek.github.io/monolog/doc/02-handlers-formatters-processors.html) to log events, so you _should_ be able to configure it to send output to STDOUT using [the log configuration samples](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/log/log-db.html), especially have a look at the StreamHandler. There's no direct way implemented and there's an open ticket about the feature [here](https://github.com/markoshust/docker-magento2-php/issues/14)

Comment: https://github.com/graycoreio/magento2-stdlogging